# How do I modify G Suite user email aliases in bulk?

Tags: email, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

I recently added a new Domain Alias to my G Suite account, and now I want to give every user an email alias ending with the new domain. I assumed this would happen automatically, but it didn't. Google's [help docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7502379?hl=en) say:

> For large organizations:  It can take more than 24 hours after verification for all users and groups to receive their alias email addresses.

But after 48 hours I still didn't see the new domain appear in email aliases for any users.

I know that I can go into the profile/user information for each user and manually add the new email alias that way, but that's quite tedious. Is there an easy way to propagate the new domain alias and create email aliases for all users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User email aliases **are** created when a new domain alias is added. However, this may not be obvious because they don't appear when you're looking at the user profile view. Here's a screenshot from my user profile showing only a single email address corresponding to my primary domain.

[image: single email alias for primary domain]

However, clicking into the Email aliases shows that there are automatically generated email aliases present for each of the added alias domains.

[image: G Suite user has alias domain email address shown in light grey]

This confirms that no action is required, only patience. And verifying that the alias has been created requires inspecting just a little bit deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that there are different ways to add another domain to a G Suite account. 1. you can add a domain as secondary domain of the primary domain and 2. you can add another domain as an alias of the primary domain, this will create an alias for each user automatically.

for more information check [this](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7502379?hl=en) G Suite article.